# jQuery Validate: Traversing to particular element by class

Tags: jquery, validation

Hopefully a simple issue:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#regform").validate({
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            $(element).parent().next().next().hide();    //works
            $(element).parent().next('div.test').hide(); //doesn't work 
        }           
    });
});


<form id="regform">
    <div class="field">
        <input name="username" id="username" type="text" class="text required" />
    </div>
    <div class="dummy">
        &nbsp;
    </div>  
    <div class="test">
        Hide this text
    </div>
</form>
```

I'm trying to get the div with the class "test" to hide upon a validation error. Traversing one-by-one works, but including a selector doesn't work.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with `siblings()` you could use `nextAll()`:

```
$(element).parent().nextAll('.test:first').hide();
```

[JS Fiddle proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FWvkP/)

The advantage of this approach is that `nextAll()` looks only to *later* siblings, whereas `siblings()` looks both ways. I'm limiting the selection to only the `:first` matched element simply because I assumed that, if you want to hide specifically, it's only the *first* item you'd want to hide.

Answer (score 0):

This will hide all .test elements directly nested in the form

```
$("#username").parent().siblings(".test").hide();
```